# What is the nationality of Felonious Gru?

Tags: character, despicable-me, despicable-me-2, minions

I wonder what is the nationality of Felonious Gru from the movie *Despicable Me*.  I have seen the movie both in English and Spanish, and both voice characterizations makes me think that he is East European (maybe Romanian), or perhaps Russian, but can't find any evidence of this.

My family recently watched the *Minions* movie, and according to them (beware, spoilers ahead)

> there are scenes in the movie that points Gru to be from England.  I believe this happens near the end of the movie, where the minions found Gru as a child near a beach I think...  and as the second half of the movie takes place in London, at least we can tell that little Gru lived there as a child.  However, that doesn't mean that he was born in England...

Comment: Um... Gru is in London in a flight-capable vehicle. Him being in London means nothing.

Comment: I recently came across a YouTube video of a guy teaching the months of the year in Turkish. I think his accent is dead-on for Gru's. See what you think. http://youtu.be/W8jP2qFt3R0

Answer (score 6):

A quick search seems to imply that no one knows.

Carrel appeared in character on Ellen DeGeneres' show and said he's from "Albuquerque, New Mexico" but there's no way to know if he was being serious or not.

It's around 1:50 in the clip below:

As you can see, she seems to doubt what he says and his response is "Don't push this topic!"

It seems completely within character for him to hedge about where he's from.

Comment: Hm, maybe it's a sensible topic, as the character has a lot of imperfections that probably will result in polemics and may hurt people's feelings if a nationality is set or defined for the character... hence the *don't push this topic*?

Comment: Despicable Me 3 introduced Gru relatives that lived in Freedonia. Gru might be from Freedonia.